# Pasar valor del ID de un option mediante javascript a span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Amigos que tal, como podría pasar el `id` de un `option` a un `javascript`para que este actualice mediante un `style` la propiedad de `background-position` en un `span`(el estilo posiciona cierta parte de una imagen que vendría ser una bandera). solo he logrado capturar el `value` y enviarlo al input. pero me falta la `imagen`, que también cambie.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() { //detectamos el evento change
    var value = $(this).val(); //sacamos el valor del select
    $('#phone').val(value); //le agregamos el valor al input (notese que el input debe tener un ID para que le caiga el valor)
  });
});
```

```css
.bp_form__field {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field__label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country {
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-input-phone-country {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c-input-phone-country__country {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

select {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

select {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country .c-input-phone-country__flag {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\25BC';
  top: 50%;
  left: 23px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 6px;
}

element.style {
  background-position: 0px -300px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  background: url(http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190112010658.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country #phone {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.bp_input_text {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 2px;
  zoom: 1;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

input {
  padding-left: .3em;
}

input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.c-input-phone-country__input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div data-component="" class="bp_form__field bp_form__field--phone ">
  <label for="phone" class="bp_form__field__label">
    Teléfono / movil
    </label>
  <div data-component="input-phone-country" class="c-input-phone-country" data-phone-country-default="pe">
    <select id="mySelect" class="c-input-phone-country__country" tabindex="-1" data-phone-country="">
      <option value="+ 971" id="25">Emiratos Árabes Unidos</option>
      <option value="+ 93" id="50">Afganistán</option>
      <option value="+ 1268" id="75">Antigua y Barbuda</option>
      <option value="+ 1264" id="100">Anguila</option>
      <option value="+ 355" id="125">Albania</option>
      <option value="+ 374" id="150">Armenia</option>
      <option value="+ 244" id="200">Angola</option>
      <option value="+ 672" id="225">Antártida</option>
      <option value="+ 54" id="250">Argentina</option>
      <option value="+ 1684" id="275">Samoa Americana</option>
      <option value="+ 43" id="300">Austria</option>
      <option value="+ 61" id="325">Australia</option>
      <option value="+ 297" id="350">Aruba</option>
      <option value="+ 994" id="400">Azerbaiyán</option>
      <option value="+ 387" id="425">Bosnia y Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="+ 1246" id="450">Barbados</option>
      <option value="+ 880" id="475">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="+ 32" id="500">Bélgica</option>
      <option value="+ 226" id="525">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="+ 359" id="550">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="+ 973" id="575">Bahréin</option>
      <option value="+ 257" id="600">Burundi</option>
      <option value="+ 229" id="625">Benín</option>
    </select>
    <span class="c-input-phone-country__flag"><span class="c-input-phone-country__flag__img" data-phone-flag="" style="background-position: 0px -250px;"></span></span>
    <input id="phone" class="bp_form__field__input bp_input_text bp_phone_input_with_help_message
    c-input-phone-country__input
    " type="text" name="phone" required="" value="" size="20" data-phone-input="" aria-describedby="bp_form_phone_msg" placeholder="+54">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<strong>la imagen:</strong> es una imgen, especificada en el css
<br>
<img src="http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190112010658.png" alt="">
```

lo que necesito es que al seleccionar un `option` este le pase su `id` que es la posición de la bandera.
y actualise el `style` de `<span class="c-input-phone-country__flag"><span class="c-input-phone-country__flag__img" data-phone-flag="" style="background-position: 0px -250px;">`

Cada `id` viene a ser la posiciona de la bandera por defecto esta en -250 que es Argentina `<option value="+ 54" id="250">Argentina</option>`

y también estoy pensando en que si escribe en el `input` el código del pais este lo busque el `option` y posicione su bandera

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo que yo haría sería colocar un data-id con la posición deseada en cada option value

```
<option value="+ 971" id="25" data-position="-1px">Emiratos Árabes Unidos</option>
```

Y ya en mi archivo js

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() { //detectamos el evento change
    var value = $(this).val(); //sacamos el valor del select
    $('#phone').val(value); //le agregamos el valor al input (notese...)
    var position = $(this).find(':selected').data('position');
    $('.c-input-phone-country__flag__img').css({
        'background-position': `0px ${position}`
    });
  });
});
```

se modifica para obtener el valor y asignarlo al span dinamicamente.

creo que se entiende bien, igual te dejo el fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mh1vw68b/2/

(no están ordenadas las banderas de acuerdo a su país.)

Comment: tu respuesta esta genial, y ahora como podría posicionar la bandera mientras escribo el código del pais, digamos que escribo el +54 por ende quiero que salga la bandera de Argentina en el `input`.

Comment: @CésarRodríguezReyes Añadiendo un listener al evento `input`, el cual se ejecutará en cada dígito añadido o quitado. La idea es capturar los primeros dígitos para ver de qué bandera se trata y mostrarla en el input. Inténtalo y publica una nueva pregunta en caso tengas algún problema.